# The day to night cycle stopped working! Help!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I used /time set day and now the sun will not go down. How do I reset the time without using /time set because I already tried that?

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
/gamerule doDaylightCycle [true/false]
```

This may fix the problem.